# Can't connect to MySQL server at /usr/local/sbin/XenConfig.pl line 333

Tags: centos7, xen

Can anyone tell me what the following error is and how to fix?

> File does not exist: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (99) at > /usr/local/sbin/XenConfig.pl line 333.

The error occurs on a Centos 7 server.

Comment: This sounds like a parsing issue, your Perl script is trying to find a FILE, but the returned string is not a valid filename but SQL error.. Please share what is on lines 325-340 in your  /usr/local/sbin/XenConfig.pl

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The hosting people tell me the error is due to the server firewall

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the XenConfig.pl file has custom code created by the company hosting the server. They advise me that the error is happening due to the server firewall.